# Перевод молитвы со старославянского языка на современный

Tags: переводы, славянизмы

Если возможно, помогите перевести на современный язык текст молитвы. Постарался написать текст как в оригинале.
Первая часть стандартная и перевода не требует, а вот со слов **рече гдь азже** понятна только совсем общая суть. Хотелось бы уточнить перевод.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Молитва на кресте]

Comment: А что из себя представляет оригинал? Я споткнулся на слове "гдь". если это "где" то оно через ять писалось, да и по грамматике здесь что-то не то...

Comment: По моему это господь. Часто видел на иконах такое сокращение..

Comment: Я отверг эту мысль, "господь" без титла и без заглавной... Нонссенс. Ладно разберемся сейчас. Я половину уже перевел, кроме этого места.

Comment: Могу скинуть на почту фото креста в хорошем разрешении.

Comment: Сделайте одолжение. Почта - в профиле. Я тогда ваше фото и вставлю в ваше сообщение, с вашего позволения, если вы не можете.

Comment: уже отправил...

Comment: Получил. Да, "господь", Вы титл не поставили, это меня сбило. И самый конец посмотрите, у вас явно ошибка  в последнем слове, я на фото не могу пока разобрать. Я Ваше фото вставляю в вопрос?

Comment: да, вставляйте...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> азже терпя...

... я же терпеливо ожидаю покаяния вашего и обращения ко мне от зол ваших, ибо прежде суда моего многие показал вам пути ко спасению и образ (пример) дал вам собою. Милую вас, добра ради в плоть облачился, и вас ради тружусь. И вас ради жаден(?) был, желая вашего спасения. Вас ради связан...

Дальше на кресте просматривается текст ".. ***вы (от)безаконiкъ***. У вас как минимум одна ошибка В вместо Б. К сожалению, мне пока это ничего не говорит.

=====================

Короче, уверился в том, что на кресте - опечатка. В самом конце "iкъ" не может быть ничем иным, кроме *"(связанъ вы wт безакон**iя**)"*. Т. е. "Къ" - это одна буква, "юс малый".  Эти объясняется и десятичное i ("иже") перед ним. Эта буква использовалась только перед гласными. С учетом этих предлагаемых правок, весь текст будет звучать примерно так.

***Крест, хранитель всей вселенной, Крест красота церковная, Крест царю держава, Крест верным утверждение, Крест ангелам слава, Крест бесу язва.
Речет Господь: я же терпеливо ожидаю покаяния вашего и обращения ко мне от зол ваших, ибо прежде суда моего многие показал вам пути ко спасению и образ (пример) дал вам собою. Милую вас, добра ради в плоть облачился, и вас ради тружусь. И вас ради алчен, желая вашего спасения. Вас ради связан вами от беззакония.***

Comment: *В самом конце "iкъ" не может быть ничем иным, кроме "(связанъ вы wт безаконiя)".* Может быть. Скорее всего, это мн. ч., род. п., т. е. "от беззаконников". Только "вы" всё путает, и я тоже ничего не понимаю.(( "Вы" означает "вас", но "связан вас" — это белиберда.(

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Оба раза нет. ***Вы*** здесь это творительный падеж, современное "Вами". Творительный падеж множественного числа мужского и среднего рода совпадал с именительным. Сравните "со товарищи". Что касается "безаконик", то даже если предположить немыслимое, что такое слово существовало в ЦСЯ (суффикс у него современный, в древности использовались другие), то оно *никак не могло писаться через **i**, эта графема использовалась только перед гласными*.

Comment: Насчёт "вы" точно, вы пролили свет на него! Действительно, обычно иже перед гласными, но я думаю всё-таки и перед согласными встречается. Как бы то ни было, но там ясно видна К, а не Я! К тому же Ъ-то откуда возьмётся после Я?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой посмотрите выше по тексту, как писался юс, в слове "спасения". При желании вполне можно принять за сочетание КЪ. А перед согласным ижк невозможно. И потом форма с нулевой флексией для существительного мужского рода крайне нехарактерна. Ну и прочая, прочая и прочая...

Comment: Да знаю я, как он пишется, и совершенно уверен, что там не он, а КЪ! И вижу я это без "специального желания" именно это увидеть. Прям впору провести голосование, кто что там видит. :)))

Comment: Посмотрел только что в Евангелии примеры с родительным падежом для "учеников" и "грешников". Там действительно "ученикъ" и "грешникъ" с иже. Только оказалось, что "иже" — это буква, похожая на нашу И, а просто "и" — это как раз палочка с двумя точками (как украинская ЙИ). Я просто уже забыл названия. То есть действительно непонятно, почему там И палочкой, но отказаться от уверенности, что там на конце КЪ, я не могу. Кстати, есть всё-таки хотя бы одно слово, где ударная И перед согласной: мїръ=world (в отличие от мир=peace).

Comment: Нашёл об этом в Википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0). Оказывается, там много исключений, и всегда пишется И палочкой перед Й. Но, конечно, слово из примера не исключение...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, насчет исключнений, "иже" и двух точек. - это все ерунда, не относящаяся к делу. Я yазываю буквы как это было принято в дореформенной орфографии. Там было принято говорить И и Иже -  http://meta.kz/interesnie-fakti/855834-russkiy-dorevolyucionnyy-alfavit-do-reformy-1918-g.html (до века 18-го обе буквы могли назвать и так и эдак) Исключения - да, были, но это касалось исключительно корневых сочетаний, не суффиксов. Две точки в старославянском обозначали совсем не то, что в украинском, фактически это было простым украшательством.

Comment: Что касается возможности использования ik в суффиксе, то я даже готов согласиться. что по какой-то прихоти безаконiкъ там написано совсем не так, как принято в других источниках (там везде И). **Но флексия!!!** Ну не было такого варианта с нулевой флексией для множественного числа мужского рода. Я вам могу сейчас все известные учебники по ЦСЯ поднять. От Гамановича до Хабургаева. Нигде такого не видел.

Comment: Конечно, две точки означают разное, я только хотел сказать, что буквы одинаковые или очень похожи. Да, исключения действительно вроде только корневые. А что касается отсутствия окончания, вот вам примеры: ученикъ (пишу русскими буквами наиболее близко) — Иоанна, гл. 6, стих 66, грешникъ — Луки, 24.7. Это означает "учеников" и "грешников", и над И стоит в таких случаях ударение дугой (называется камора).

Comment: Без ссылок, простите: беззаконник = грешник. Перед этим словом стоит предлог О. Завязать = воспрепятствовать, не допустить, опекать. Итого, вариант концовки текста: Пекусь о вас грешных ради. При том, что Отъяти беззаконие = простить грехи, концовка может  выглядеть так: Пекусь вас ради о прощении грехов ваших.

Comment: *Без ссылок, простите* - Предлог О не писался через От. Именно для того, чтобы различать. Остальное - уж очень большая натяжка.